# Find the scalars

Tags: matrices

If possible, find scalars 
c1, c2, and c3, so that the following is true.

$$c_1(3, 2, -5) + c_2(-3, 3, 3) + c_3(-3, 8, 1) = (3, -3, 4)$$

I have no idea where to start. I think I have to make it into rref, but I am unsure. Can someone explain how to do this. Please.

Comment: It's a simple set of equations. You can solve it using Gauss-elimination or basic matrix calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Its possibly the question is:$$c_1(3, 2, -5) + c_2(-3, 3, 3) + c_3(-3, 8, 1) = (3, -3, 4)$$

Then solve the system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
3c_1-3c_2-3c_3 =3\\
2c_1+3c_2+8c_3 =-3\\
-5c_1+3c_2+c_3 =4
\end{cases}$$